# How to write a function to calculate the mean of some columns in a dataframe in r?

Tags: r

I need to add a new column with the results calculated from the mean value of other columns.

For example:

```
A     B     C     D      E
1     2     3     4      ?
```

the question mark should equal to `mean(2, 3, 4)`

I wrote my code like this

`df_new <- df %>% mutate(new_column = rowMeans(dplyr::select(., B:D))`

But because I have a really big data frame, I have to repeat this process many times, is it possible for me to write a function to make it easier? I really don't know where to start.

Comment: *"But because I have a really big data frame, I have to repeat this process many times"* sounds like your frame might be better pivoted into a longer shape.

Answer (score 0):

If your data.frame looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4)
df
  A B C D
1 1 2 3 4
```

you can get the mean you asked for like this:

```
data.frame(df,E=mean(as.numeric(df[,2:4])))
  A B C D E
1 1 2 3 4 3
```

or means for a data.frame with more rows like this:

```
data.frame(df,E=rowMeans(df[,2:4]))
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I did, but actually I need to add more columns. I have 59 columns in total and need to add more columns, and those new columns should be the mean of BCD, then mean of EFG, then mean of HIJ and so on. Of course I can repeat what I did before, but I am just curious about what I am supposed to do if I want to write a function on this.

Comment: `threecolMean <- function(start,df) {
 data.frame(df,RM=rowMeans(df[,start:(start+2)]))
}
threecolMean(2,df)
`
this might get you started, you could loop over this function or try some sort of `apply`